# React native, React Navigation integration issue undefined is not an object getStateForAction

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

So I've been follow [this](https://shift.infinite.red/react-navigation-drawer-tutorial-a802fc3ee6dc) tutorial and adapting for what I need.

I've checked the other answer but can't quite make out what I'm missing?

For the search engines, the error is: undefined is not an object, router, getStateForAction

[image]

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'
import reducers from './reducers'
import {View} from 'react-native'


import ReduxNavigation from './components/Navigation/ReduxNavigation'

const initialState = ReduxNavigation.router.getStateForAction(ReduxNavigation.router.getActionForPathAndParams('AddItems'));

const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    const newState = ReduxNavigation.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
    return newState || state
}

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        ...reducers,
        nav: navReducer,
    })
)

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                    <ReduxNavigation/>
            </Provider>
        )
    }

}
```

ReduxNavigation:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as ReactNavigation from 'react-navigation'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PrimaryNav from './PrimaryNav'

// here is our redux-aware our smart component
function ReduxNavigation (props) {
    const { dispatch, nav } = props
    const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch,
        state: nav
    })

    return <PrimaryNav navigation={navigation} />
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

PrimaryNav:

```
import React from 'react'
import {StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import AddItemsWrapper from '../AddItemsWrapper'
import {Text} from 'react-native'

const noTransitionConfig = () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
        duration: 0,
        timing: Animated.timing,
        easing: Easing.step0
    }
})

const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
    screen: {screen: AddItemsWrapper}
}, {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
})

const drawerButton = (navigation) =>
    <Text
        style={{padding: 5, color: 'white'}}
        onPress={() => {
            // Coming soon: navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')
            // https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/2492
            if (navigation.state.index === 0) {
                navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
            } else {
                navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')
            }
        }
        }>Menu</Text>

const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    DrawerStack: {screen: DrawerStack}
}, {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#4C3E54'},
        title: 'Welcome!',
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        gesturesEnabled: false,
        headerLeft: drawerButton(navigation)
    })
})

// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
    drawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}, {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    title: 'Main',
    initialRouteName: 'loginStack',
    transitionConfig: noTransitionConfig
})

export default PrimaryNav
```

Comment: Wild guess. Can you remove `View` from App class render and make the `ReduxNavigation` direct child of `Provider`?

Comment: Yep done! No affect.

Comment: In react-navigation docs there is a `initialState` creation. Maybe its because you are missing it. Please check [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux#Redux-Integration) out.

Comment: Hmm good try there, i've updated my example above, but basically the same error moves up to that initialState creating.

Comment: In the example its getting the initialstate from the initially created navigator, but in your example you are trying to create the initial state from the redux aware navigator. It might be related to that.

Comment: Yeah you got it the navReducer needs to use the NON redux navigator, wanna post an answer? Thanks good work on that, I'm such a donut! FYI you don't need initialState in this example, not sure why.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. Because I will not be able to give much context to my answer its better if you answer your own post with the code how you solved the issue. Maybe someone later give a better explanation on _why_.

Comment: Ok if you're sure!

Comment: Yeah its ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer actually rather simple in the App.js you need to build the navReducer from plain navigation component rather than Redux one. Thanks to benneygennel for helping through comments! So this:

```
const navReducer = (state, action) => {

    const newState = ReduxNavigation.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
    return newState || state
}
```

Becomes:

```
const navReducer = (state, action) => {

    const newState = PrimaryNav.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
    return newState || state
}
```